# Getting closest div with specific id and innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 divs that are exactly the same, inside each div i have a select option input .. all divs have the same id so i want to get the nearest div of select and then do innerHTML inside.

So i want something like:

`$(this).closest('div[maybeidhere?]').innerhtml ='whole content here';`

Thanks in advance

EDIT :  Ignore the same id, lets say all have same class

```
    <div> 
        <select id="faculty" onchange="inchange(this)">
                    <option value="fos">Faculty of Science</option>
                    <option value="fot">Faculty of Information Technology</option>
                   <option value="foe">Faculty of Engineering</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
         <div class="degreediv"></div>

        </div>
                <script>
function inchange(input){


    if($(input).val()=="fot"){
     $(this).closest('div[.degreediv]').innerhtml ='FOT CONTENT';

    }
    else if($(input).val()=="fos"){
        $(this).closest('div[.degreediv]').innerhtml ='FOS CONTENT';
    }
    else if($(input).val()=="foe"){
        $(this).closest('div[.degreediv]').innerhtml ='FOE CONTENT';
    }
    else if($(input).val()=="other"){
        $(this).closest('div[.degreediv]').innerhtml ='other CONTENT';
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Closest to what? `:first-of-type`?

Comment: Since id's should be unique, start fixing that, then post the code you have so we can see before suggest anything

Comment: `id` must be different, it must uniquely identify an element on the page. `class` can be used more than once.

Comment: Ok let's ignore the id, let's say i don't have ID for the divs.. closest div to my select option

Comment: See the update to my answer. You can't use `.innerhtml` on a jQuery wrapper.

Comment: Could you include some example of the HTML you want returned; the way you ask the question seems to suggest you want to retrieve the `innerHTML` of the `<div>` containing the `<select>` element, but I think you meant to ask how to retrieve the `innerHTML` of the element with an `id` equal to the value of the chosen `<option>`? Either way, please show enough HTML that we can reproduce your problem, and enough clarity that we don't have to guess at the problem you're trying to solve. Please: read both the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Since select is inside the divs you can rather use .Parent() function

$(this).parent().innerhtml;

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
    <option value="value1">1</option>
    <option value="value2">2</option>
    <option value="value3">3</option>
</select>
<div>this is div 1</div>
<div>this is div 2</div>
...
<div>this is div n</div>
```

If your code resembles this then:

```
$textOfDiv = $('select + div').val(); // selects text inside first DIV element
```

or

```
$htmlOfDiv = $('select + div').html(); // selects html inside first DIV element
```

Note that `jQuery` selector works similar to `CSS` selector.

**Refer to:**

`CSS Selector Reference`

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

`jQuery Selector Reference`

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/